# ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2)

Tags: php, apache, yii2, mod-security

I have installed the apache mod security on the server. In a particular url, while sending the post data, it throws the below error

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?i:[\\"'].{0,}?[,].{0,}(((v|(\\\\\\\\u0076)|(\\\\166)|(\\\\x76))[^a-z0-9]{0,}(a|(\\\\\\\\u0061)|(\\\\141)|(\\\\x61))[^a-z0-9]{0,}(l|(\\\\\\\\u006C)|(\\\\154)|(\\\\x6C))[^a-z0-9]{0,}(u|(\\\\\\\\u0075)|(\\\\165)|(\\\\x75))[^a-z0-9]{0,}(e|(\\\\\\\\u0065)|(\\\\145)|(\\\\x65))[^a-z0-9]{0,}(O|(\\\\\\ ..." at ARGS:form1. [file "D:/xampp/apache/conf/modsecurity/07_XSS_XSS.conf"] [line "299"] [id "213020"] [rev "1"] [msg "COMODO WAF: IE XSS Filters - Attack Detected."] [data "Matched Data: \\x22name\\x22:\\x22SelOrginCountry\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x22Oman\\x22},{\\x22name\\x22:\\x22Tbl[CountryMst_Fk]\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x22141\\x22},{\\x22name\\x22:\\x22[CompanyName]\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x22sample company\\x22},{\\x22name\\x22:\\x22Tbl[RegistrationNo]\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x221357911\\x22},{\\x22name\\x22:\\x22Tbl[RegistrationYear]\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x2217-12-2019\\x22},{\\x22name\\x22:\\x22StyleCorp\\x22,\\x..."] [hostname "xxx.xx.x.1xx"] [uri "/appname/index.php"] [unique_id "XiFXUcCoAYgAABccyaUAAACQ"]
```

I checked the postdata for the suspicious term, when a string starts with 'of', it throws the 403 error, if I remove that,  I'm getting status 200

Need any ideas to resolve the above issue?

Comment: are you using plesk

Comment: I'm using apache server installed and configured with mod security.